# Realtek onboard sound disappeared

Tags: audio, drivers, asus, realtek-hd-audio

Motherboard ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.  PRIME B360M-A

From one day to the next Windows 10 no longer detected the onboard realtek audio only listing the HDMI output as a audio device. No hardware modifications were made in the meantime.

Attempted remedies:

- Ran hardware troubleshoot wizard
- driver reinstall
- windows 10 clean reinstall and downgrade to version Version  10.0.17134, Build 17134
- installation of audio drivers versions 6.0.8702.1, 6.0.1.8339 from the Asus website
- checked Bios, confirmed hd audio is enabled
- booted Ubuntu to check for detection of Realtek device, none found

Post installation of the audio drivers I'd expected the Realtek device manager to show up after plugging in an in/output device into the audio port but this program has gone AWOL with the device.
Right now the only audio device Windows lists is my NVidia graphics card.

Is there a way to test whether the onboard audio is functional?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your tests, "checked Bios, confirmed hd audio is enabled," and "booted Ubuntu to check for detection of Realtek device, none found," is confirmation this is likely a **hardware** issue, not software (i.e., OS, drivers, etc.).

One last firmware fix to try would be to *turn off* onboard audio *and Fast Start* in BIOS, perform a full reboot (shutdown /s), go back to BIOS and re-enable onboard audio, and reboot again.

Some things to check in hardware:

- It is possible a connector has loosened, or even that [fungal hyphae](https://apps.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/p005752.pdf) have pushed into the connector. Remove and reseat cards and power connectors.
- Visually check with a magnifier around the audio section of the board for a bad solder joint. Also, one side of a surface-mount device can break loose, due to vibration, direct pressure, or heating and cooling. *If you are experienced with microelectronics and have the equipment*, the component can be resoldered. (Which I had to do, for example, on a mechanical keyboard, when a diode came loose.)
- A component might have gone bad in the audio circuitry. Either the component would need to be found and replaced (of varying degrees of difficulty, from simply bypassing an open surface-mount capacitor to *trying* to remove and replace the Realtek audio IC without destroying the whole board). If that is the issue, the mother board may need to be replaced. It might be possible to add an external audio card, though you've already payed for the 8-channel onboard audio circuitry.

How could a component be damaged? A nearby lightning strike or electrical surge could send too much electricity through lines from a powered speaker, or through inductive pickup. If you have powered devices plugged in, it's safer to have them running to the same, surge-protected power strip that the PC uses.